# Append a Range into an existing Excel.Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I've an Excel.Range of a whole sheet obtained like this:

```
Excel.Range rngMediaPacks = ((Excel.Worksheet)liVAD_plus.Worksheets["Media Packs"]).UsedRange;
```

Now I need to append/inject/insert-at-the-bottom this Range into another existing Excel.Worksheet referenced as liVAD_plus.Worksheets["Express Program"]).

Should be easy, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I had it working:

```
//WorksheetMerge is a custom method (see below)
WorksheetMerge((Excel.Worksheet)liVAD_plus.Worksheets["Media Packs"], (Excel.Worksheet)liVAD_plus.Worksheets["Express Program"]);

//
static public void WorksheetMerge(Excel.Worksheet origine, Excel.Worksheet destinazione)
    {
        Excel.Range rngOrigine = origine.UsedRange;
        rngOrigine.Copy(Type.Missing);

        Excel.Range rngDestinazioneLastCell = destinazione.UsedRange.Offset[destinazione.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 0];

        rngDestinazioneLastCell.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
    }
```